# Nested radicals notation

Tags: notation, nested-radicals

Is there any convenient notation for things like: $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}}$

Maybe using limits?

I'm asking purely notational-wise.

Comment: My experience has been that they just kind of stack them on top of each other, $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\ldots}}}$

Comment: Do you want a notation that is precise in the sense that there is no potential ambiguity, i.e., no ellipses? If you don't need that level of rigor, Brent's "stacking" notation seems like the best option, and that's certainly what one sees most in practice.

Comment: You can recursively define a function $f(n)$ as $f(n)=\sqrt{n+\sqrt{f(n+1)}}$.

$f(1)$ will you the expression in your question. This works quite a bit like continued fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\dots}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\dots+\sqrt{n}}}}$